# Why the split function is not throwing unexpected result in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a gridview in that I've taken a GridView with 2 columns (1 TemplateField & 1 BoundField).

I'm binding the same data column (named 'Stage') to both the grid columns.

Original Text Value: `1;#Original u/s 139#Test`

Expected result in Column 1:   `1;#Original u/s 139#Test`

Expected result in Coulmn 2:   `Original u/s 139#Test`

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Stage" HeaderText="Original Value" SortExpression="Stage" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Using Split Function">
      <ItemTemplate>   
             <%# Eval("Stage").ToString().Contains("#") ? Eval("Stage").ToString().Split('#')[1] : Eval("Stage")  %>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

***Result:***

```
Original Value           | Using Split Function

1;#Original u/s 139#Test | Original u/s 139
```

In column 2 result **should be** `Original u/s 139#Test`.

My question is why split function is splitting the value in column 2 twice?

Comment: Because `Split` splits the string on **all occurences** of the split character. You have 2 `#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Split` splits the string on all occurrences of the given `char` or `string`. So your string will be split in 3 strings:

```
[0] 1;
[1] Original u/s 139
[2] Test
```

You should use `substring` from first occurrence of `#`

```
Eval("Stage").ToString().Contains("#") ? Eval("Stage").ToString().Substring(Eval("Stage").IndexOf('#') + 1) : Eval("Stage")
```